# Redux causing 40+ re-renders on single page: would like help identifying/fixing issue

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am working on the dashboard site for a music theory app company where users can manage their info, courses, assignments, media content etc.

The site is built using React hooks and Redux Toolkit. The current page I am working on is for a teacher user to edit an assignment set (assignment details and any exercises associated with that assignment). We want the user to be able to navigate to each assignment edit page by typing, so the url is something like `course/{courseID}/assignment/{assignmentID}`. This means that anytime this page loads I need to make API calls to grab any back-end data I need.

My overall Redux store object is fairly simple. Here's an example of it pertaining to what I'm grabbing on the page in question:

```
store: {
  singleCourse: {
    courseInfo: <courseInfoObj>,
    students: [...<studentsObjs>],
    assignments: [...<assignmentObjs>],
  },
  singleAssignment: {
    assignmentInfo: <assignmentInfoObj>,
    exercises: [...<exerciseObjs>],
  },
  contentLibrary: {
    library: [...<libraryObjs>]
  }
}
```

The page is structured so I have a single `useEffect` that uses `batch` to group all `dispatch` actions I need to make. Then, I grab what I need from the Redux store with `useSelector`. On this page I need to `dispatch` 6 different actions (to 6 different API routes) to get all the data I need, which is stored on the 3 reducers listed above. To get the data from Redux, I'm doing `const {singleCourse, singleAssignment, contentLibrary} = useSelector(state => state)`

I've noticed that the page is re-rendering up to 40+ times (and the more exercises there are to list in an assignment, the more re-renders there are). In my debugging I've noticed that when I remove any `useSelector` calls, the number of re-renders drops significantly. Note that I'm keeping track of the renders very crudely via a numeric variable defined just before my function page and incrementing/logging it before my JSX return.

Can grabbing things from the Redux store with useSelector be the cause of this insane amount of re-renders? I've done some research about using memoized selectors to prevent excessive re-rendering (and I can use `createSelector` from Redux Toolkit for this), but the examples are not relevant at all to my case and for the life of me I can't figure out how to use it in my case.

Also, is it bad practice that on this particular page I dispatch 6 different actions that update 3 separate reducers?

The pages load fairly quickly and are responsive, but I'm worried that all these re-renders are/will cause major issues.

Thanks

Edit: here's more code for reference.

AssignmentDetailPage.tsx

```
const AssignmentDetailPage = () => {
  const { courseID, assignmentID } = useParams();

// dispatches

  useEffect(() => {
    batch(() => {
      
      dispatch(getCourseDetail(courseID));
      dispatch(getCourseStudents(courseID));
      dispatch(getCourseAssignments(courseID));
      dispatch(getAssignmentAndDocuments(assignmentID));
      dispatch(listAssignmentDueDateExtensions(assignmentID));
      dispatch(getEntireContentLibrary());
    })
  }, [dispatch]);



  // Grabbing  from Redux store.



  const selectedCourse = useHarmoniaSelector(state=> state.selectedCourse);
  const selectedAssignment = useHarmoniaSelector(state => state.selectedAssignment);
  const contentLibrary = useHarmoniaSelector(state => state.contentLibrary);


  // Grabbing assignment info from assignments state.

  const assignment = selectedAssignment.assignment as Assignment || {};

  const dueDateExtensions = selectedAssignment.dueDateExtensions as DueDateExtension[];


  const documents = selectedAssignment.documents || [] as Document[];


  // Grabbing array of assignments and finding assignmentIndex of current assignment.
  const courseAssignments = selectedCourse.assignments as Assignment[] || [];

  const courseStudents = selectedCourse.students || [] as CourseStudent[];

}
```

Here's an example of redux stuff with the selectedAssignment:

selectedAssignment.ts

```
type SelectedAssignmentInitialState = {
  assignment?: Assignment | null,
  documents?: Document[] | null,
  dueDateExtensions?: DueDateExtension[] | null
}
const initialState: SelectedAssignmentInitialState = {};

// actions
export const getAssignmentAndDocuments = createAsyncThunk
<Assignment, number, {rejectValue: void}>
('assignments/getAssignmentDetail', async(assignmentID, {dispatch, rejectWithValue}) => {
  try{
    const response = await API.get(`/api/assignments/${assignmentID}`);
    return response.data.data as Assignment;
  }catch(e){
    dispatch(pushErrorNotification(errorMessage(e.data)));
    return rejectWithValue();
  }
});

export const listAssignmentDueDateExtensions = createAsyncThunk<DueDateExtension[], number, {rejectValue: void}  >('assignment/listAssignmentDueDateExtensions', async (assignmentID, {dispatch, rejectWithValue}) => {
  try{
    const response = await API.get(`/api/assignments/${assignmentID}/due-day-extensions`);
    return response.data.data as DueDateExtension[];
  }catch(e){
    dispatch(pushErrorNotification(e.data));
    return rejectWithValue();
  }
});

// reducer

const selectedAssignmentSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'selectedAssignment',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
    .addCase(
      getAssignmentAndDocuments.fulfilled,
      ((state, {payload}) => {
        // assignmentDetail is everything but documents; documents kept on separate key in state obj to keep things simpler.
        const {course, documents, due_at, id, released_at, set_key, show_after_due, title, weight} = payload;
        state.assignment = {course, due_at, id, released_at, set_key, show_after_due, title, weight};
        state.documents = documents;
      })
      )
.addCase(listAssignmentDueDateExtensions.fulfilled, ((state, {payload}) => {
        state.dueDateExtensions = payload;
      }))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to profile the application to find your real bottlenecks. It's not encouraged to write perfectly cached code for example and memoize everything, as that's premature optimization that affects developer productivity maintainability/bugs etc.

With that out of the way, it does make sense to try our best to code things performantly.

This is a good read on what to put in state, and try to leave out "derived data" like calculations. https://redux.js.org/usage/deriving-data-selectors

This is a good read on how `useSelector` works:
https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#performance

I'm going to cherry pick some stuff that I think applies:

`useSelector` runs after every action. If the returned response differs in reference comparison to the last result, it will force the component to re-render.

Your `useSelector` call is returning the state object. The state object will differ by reference equality on every action, so it will always force a re-render.

Make a selector that returns each item in the state tree. Assuming you aren't creating new objects unless that part of state changes, those selectors won't cause re-renders by default.

Immer/Redux toolkit for example would preserve unchanged state tree portions. You should try to with standard redux as well, e.g. return old state unless reducer is acting on that state.

That's probably the big one. You should investigate exactly what is causing the re-renders, after the basic useSelector optimization (don't return whole state tree), and start looking for appropriate solutions.

> Also, is it bad practice that on this particular page I dispatch 6 different actions that update 3 separate reducers?

I don't think it's bad. That's not a lot. One redux toolkit async action will fire 3 actions.

> The pages load fairly quickly and are responsive, but I'm worried that all these re-renders are/will cause major issues.

Yeah, I think you need to keep an eye out for sure but again careful about premature optimization. I'd be trying to make sure no major mistakes are being made (like not leaning on useSelector default reference checks) but no more optimization beyond that. Leave room for code complexity for the proven bottlenecks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! You stated: "Make a selector that returns each item in the state tree. Assuming you aren't creating new objects unless that part of state changes, those selectors won't cause re-renders by default." Can you give an example of this? Thanks again

Comment: @OnceAgainNoNet `const output = useSelector(state => state.foobar)` vs `const { foobar } = useSelector(state => state)`. This is likely causing lots of renders, since the root state object would be new every time. You can also use createSelector, as you said, which will also help with selector time (and not just render time). I actually find createSelector really good in general for cleaner code/"derived data" patterning, and you get the perf for free.

Comment: Gotcha. So I should do something like `const singleCourse = useSelector(state=> state.selectedCourse)`? Even when I do this for all I'm grabbing it can still render over 50 times if there is a lot of data. Also, how would I go about using createSelector? I'm a bit confused on all of the examples.

Comment: @OnceAgainNoNet are you using Redux toolkit and thus Immer? Otherwise make sure you're not changing state in your slices if not needed. Then you miss out on cheap reference checks. You should figure out what is changing too, you can add an equality check override as the second argument. useSelector(..., (prev, next) => { prev !== next && console.log("I caused the change"); return prev === next}.

Comment: @OnceAgainNoNet At this point we need to dig into what actually is causing those re-renders with certainty.  Feel free to paste your profiler graph of the 50 renders too. How are you counting? 50 **total** renders caused by the root level component changing is expected. 50 re-renders of the same component is not.

Comment: Yep, I'm using Redux toolkit. I'm counting the renders by doing `console.count()` just before the `return()` of my React function component.

Comment: @OnceAgainNoNet use the React profiler to understand what is re-rendering. console.count() either means that component or an ancestor re-rendered. If it's happening 50 times in one place, let's start figuring out why. Feel free to share more code, redux dev tools export, etc

Comment: Thank you so so much for your responses! Another question: where exactly is a good spot where I should use the React profiler in this instance? I'm working on setting up my redux dev tools again (it's currently not working) and that should help. Lastly, I'm totally willing to share more code, I just don't know what would be  pertinent in this situation. Thanks so much again!

Comment: I got my Redux dev tools working. What do you mean by `redux dev tools export`?

Comment: @OnceAgainNoNet use the profiler to capture the 50 renders in whatever way you can. It could be from startup, or if you are able to somehow trigger the download easily it would be helpful to separate the startup noise from what the redux actions cause specifically. So click record, click the button that causes the issues, then stop. Redux dev tools export gives the actions but i guess not the state.. I wanted to see what you're doing to the state.

Comment: Would it help if I shared more code for how I'm using the dispatch/selectors on my page function component and also code for how I'm setting the Redux state with that action?

Comment: @OnceAgainNoNet absolutely. At this point whatever data you can dump is helpful, in the post, codesandbox etc.

Comment: Alright, updated my post to have more code. Let me know if that helps give you a better idea. Thanks

Comment: @OnceAgainNoNet awesome. Good looking code! Looks like you are making a lot of async fetching, not sure what the other reducers look like, but at first glance, 6x actions = minimum 6 actions, which may fire 3 actions per async so 18 actions. I'm not seeing where you'd get 50 quite yet, but we're getting there. So this page without the selectors renders once? You should definitely add the selector equality check to see which selectors are the issue. I can tell the slice you pasted does 1x update per fulfilled of the 2 actions, so that's 2/50 extra renders accounted for.

Comment: @OnceAgainNoNet add the `(prev, next) => { prev!== next && console.log("selector x forcing render");  return prev === next}` to your selectors. I can't imagine this adding up to that many. To be clear, your `console.count()` is in this component? It should mount, fire off the getters, and your selectors would be the sole render cause. Also log your useEffect. If you're using strict mode react 18 it would fire twice, doubling these actions. Check redux dev tools for expected action count/behavior.

Comment: Yep, my `console.count()` is in this component. Actually, without the selectors this component renders 16 times (the useEffect runs once). Something I forgot is that there is a sidebar on the left side of the page that has the information (title, and links using the proper course id) for the currently selected course. On that sidebar component, we grab the course title via a `useSelector` from the selectedCourse state using the courseID param.

Comment: Also, running the `prev, next` stuff logged selectedCourse 3x, selectedAssignment 2x and contentLibrary 1x

Comment: ignore my last comment. The correct numbers are selectedAssignment x13, course x3, and content library x1. Would you like to see the render return of my AssignmentDetailPage function? Maybe there could be something there too. Thanks again!

Comment: I got it down from 53 to 28 renders. I forgot that (long story short) each exercise in an assignment set stored as selectedAssignment has a download link. That file url is stored separately than the rest of the data. I wrote this code a while ago and stupidly decided to attach this url to each document immediately once it was loaded into redux. But now I might just make that dispatch call only when a user clicks "download". Is 28 renders acceptable?

Comment: @OnceAgainNoNet what did you do to reduce? I don't understand why selectedAssignment would state change 13 times. That means an action modified that slice of state, and why would it when you're just fetching. It's a little concerning and it would be fun to fix, but yeah at the end of the day it's not a big deal, especially if it's a one time cost to populate state.

Comment: @OnceAgainNoNet But great that the other selectors are not updating that frequently. If it started to get crazy, you can always add a loading indicator or something. I also don't really understand why a sidebar would make your page component re-render. Does it _also_ fetch data?

Comment: The sidebar also fetches data: course info (to show title and id for links) and user info (to verify if user is a teacher & can access certain course/page links). I'm not sure if that's causing any re-renders on the page component. Also, re: the download url stuff, I actually was changing the state, newly appending a url key which previously didn't exist (value of which is the url string from the return of an api call made for each exercise after everything loads) to each object in the array of exercise objects for the selectedAssignment.  Sorry if I wasn't clearer in my earlier explanation.

Comment: @OnceAgainNoNet got it. The sidebar probably shouldn't cause many on the main page though. If you get more SO reputation we can start a chat. Otherwise email me and we can review it if you want.

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to say that I have really, really appreciated you taking the time to help me. I've already been able to pinpoint some problems and make improvements thanks to your advice. I am super grateful! I'd like to take you up on your email offer if you don't mind. I don't see your email in your profile though. Unless you mean contacting you through the department.nyc site. Thanks again!

Comment: @OnceAgainNoNet yeah it's no problem, I like to help and it makes me solve problems I don't have directly so it goes both ways. It's yuji@department.nyc